# Back slash in the csv file

Tags: java, mysql, database, csv

In my application I am reading a csv file into DB through "load data local infile" filename command in sql. In case when a back slash comes in one of the field the adjacent field get merged. How to ignore the back slash when reading a file into DB.

Example,

"abcd", "efgh\", "ijk"

it goes to table as 
col1     |  col2    | col3 
abcd     |  efghijk | null

where I want this to go as 
col1     |  col2    | col3 
abcd     |  efgh    | ijk

any pointer would be helpful.

Thanks,
Ashish

Answer (score 4):

By default LOAD DATA uses \ as the escape character. Consider your input:

```
"abcd", "efgh\", "ijk"
```

That sequence `\"` is interpreted as a literal non-enclosing quote, not a backslash followed by a quote.

The *best* solution is to properly escape backslashes in your CSV file, e.g.:

```
"abcd", "efgh\\", "ijk"
```

If you cannot do that, you can disable escaping in your LOAD DATA INFILE statement by adding `ESCAPED BY ''` to the statement. That will prevent it from recognizing \ as an escape character, but keep in mind it will disable all other escape sequences in your input file as well. That will also import `efgh\`, the backslash will not be ignored.

If importing `efgh\` is unacceptable then you will have to fix the format of your input file, or remove the trailing \ later on in your application logic or with another SQL query.

See [MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) for more information about file format options.

Hope that helps.