# Is a back slash followed by a double quote valid as per CSV spec?

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I am trying to parse a CSV file with openCSV CSVReader, I have some records in the file like this...

```
"npg6851",,"Wonderful reminder\","This is perfect, I always wanted", ,"5","Nancy88","published"
```

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064382/3223841) indicated, that sequence \" is interpreted as a literal non-enclosing quote and the parser tries to read everything afterwards are one value (regarding any comma delimiters).

Is this considered valid according to CSV specifications?

Comment: There is no CSV spec; it's a wild tangle. This is one of the biggest challenges with CSV. Various CSV parsers have configuration options regarding quoting.

Comment: @chrylis there actually is one: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180 from 2005, populair programs like libreoffice follow the RFC, and by doing so, they even support csv's containing newlines in the values

Answer (score 1):

Looks like according to the [CSV RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt), there are no issues with using backslash in a quoted CSV field, so it is valid.

This makes sense, because this issue is strictly Java-based (and any other programming language that uses \ as its escape character). Solving this, however, seems to have a very difficult solution.

Comment: Most people don't read the CSV spec when they make a parser, leading to all sorts of issues like the OP is saying

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with the language's internal string escaping unless the question is about an inline constant string read as CSV.